# Xamarin Forms - Get custom control runtime (with valueconverter?)

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls, ivalueconverter

I have a Xamarin forms application. It has a page. That page has a listview. The listviews is bind to a sourcelist. What I want is to decide what custom control to use based on a specific property that each item in the list has. How can I achieve this?

It is also required that the custom control binds to values from the list.

I tried the following:

```
                <ContentView Content="{Binding IsPriority, Converter={StaticResource RoadIndicatorBackgroundValueConverter}}" ControlText="{Binding TowingOrder.Location.RoadIndicator}"></ContentView>
```

That won't work because I can't bind with the ControlText of the specific custom control.

[image]

The image above shows the problem. The A1, A50 and the blue icons are all custom controls, those aren't images. There are some more of these custom controls. I can't just make 10 datatemplates right and copy paste everything? That would be so much duplicate code. Can't I just use a base object in a datatemplate, and bind a property with a converter and use a switch/case to decide which custom control to return?

Comment: You could use DataTemplateSelector . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector .

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I have a large datatemplate and there is only a single difference, than this solution doesn't seem very clean in my opinion. Are there any alternatives to decrease code-dublicate? And sorry that I have created two posts, I can't just figure it out.

Comment: You could provide the effects (like screen shot) which you want to achieve .

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: You just need to binding the color and text .The cell is similar .

Comment: Its not o nly the color and text, in this example yes, but there are other icons that look a little bit different, for example, there is a circular one and a triangle.

Comment: And if each cell does have one of those different custom controls (maybe later in combination with other custom controls) there will be a lot of datatemplates..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211200/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-m-yil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good design to binding the content of whole layout in runtime.

From the screen shot , it seems that each cell are similar .So you could create a base Custom Control and define all controls in advance and binding the property`IsVisible` in code behind . Then set its value to control which element should been displayed .

If there are do many dig differences between the cells , use **DataTemplateSelector** is better .